# Headers changing when reading data from csv or tsv in R

Tags: r, csv

I'm trying to read a data file into R but every time I do R changes the headers. I can't see any way to control this in the documentation from the `read` function.

I have the same data saved as both a csv and a tsv but get the same problem with both.

The headers in the data file look like this when I open it in excel or in the console:

```
cod name_mun    age_class   1985    1985M   1985F   1986    1986M   1986F
```

But when I read it into R using either `read.csv('my_data.csv')` or `read.delim('my_data.tsv')` R changes the headers to this:

```
> colnames(my_data)


[1] "ï..cod"        "name_mun"      "age_class"     "X1985"         "X1985M"        "X1985F"        "X1986"        
  [8] "X1986M"        "X1986F"
```

Why does R do this and how can I prevent it from happening?

Comment: Could you upload your tsv file or part of it so that we can reproduce the error and try to solve it? (like, the actual file, not re-typing the values here as this may not be the same)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share the data because it's confidential

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are seeing two different things here.

1. The "ï.." on the first column comes from having a byte order mark at the beginning of your file.   Depending on how you created the file,  you may be able to save as just ASCII or even just UTF-8 without a BOM to get rid of that.
2. R does not like to have variable names that begin with a digit. If you look at the help page `?make.names` you will see

> A syntactically valid name consists of letters, numbers and the dot or
>   underline characters and starts with a letter or the dot not followed
>   by a number. Names such as ".2way" are not valid, and neither are the
>   reserved words.

You can get around that when you read in your data by using the `check.names` argument to read.csv  possibly like this.

```
my_data = read.csv(file.choose(), check.names = FALSE)
```

That will keep the column names as numbers. It will also change the BOM to be the full BOM "ï»¿".

Comment: Thanks, that worked to remove X's before the numbers. To get rid of the BOM I saved it as CSV instead of CSV UTF-8 in excel and then reloaded it into R